# An equivalence relation in primitive permutation group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I try to understand the notion of primitive permutation group by reading Rotman's book page 257. Rotman's definition of block is the following:

If $X$ is a $G$-set, then a block is a subset $B$ of $X$ such that for each $g \in G$, either $gB=B$ or $gB \cap B = \varnothing$.

It also says "...If $X$ is a $G$-set and $B$ is a block, then there is an equivalence relation on $X$ given by $x \equiv y$ if there is some $gB$ containing both $x$ and $y$."

But I couldn't show the transitivity. My sketch is the following:

Let $x \equiv y$ and $y \equiv z$. Then $\exists g_{1}B$ containing both $x,y$ and $\exists g_{2}B$ containing both $y,z$. Suppose $g_{1}B \cap B =g_{2}B \cap B = \varnothing $. In this case I cannot find a subset $g_{3}B$ containing both $x$ and $z$. My guess is that $g_{1}B \cap g_{2}B \neq \varnothing$ implies $g_{1}B=g_{2}B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. Suppose there exists $y \in g_1B \cap g_2B$.

Then $g_1 b_1 = g_2 b_2$ for some $b_1, b_2 \in B$. Then $b_2 = g_2^{-1} g_1 b_1$. This means $B \cap g_2^{-1} g_1 B \neq \emptyset$. Now the definition of block implies that $g_2^{-1} g_1 B = B$.

It follows that $g_1 B = g_2 B$. Transitivity follows.

Comment: Another point is that the book does not say the action is transitive on page 257 of Rotman's book. I think it is a necessary condition. Right? Otherwise the union of $gB$ 's where for all $g \in G$ cannot give $X$ if $G$ acts on $X$ trivially.

Comment: Reflexivity does appear to be a problem. For an arbitrary $x \in X$, there need not be a $gB$ containing $x$. However, we can imagine non-transitive actions with blocks $B$ where this is an equivalence relation. If the given block $B$ satisfies $X = \cup gB$, then everything works. If the action is transitive, this always happens, but it is not hard to construct reasonable non-transitive actions where this equivalence relation makes sense.